# Temporarily remove control from tab order (round)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel with many controls on it. Tab order is assigned. I want to remove some control from tab order (round). And then restore it. How ?

runtime

.net 2.0 (please, no linq)

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`TabStop` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx) to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `TabStop` property of a control to `false` will prevent it from being included in the tab order. To restore it, just set `TabStop` to `true` again.